# Select a range of list items with CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a list (menu) with a dynamic number of items:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>bla</li>
    <li>bla</li>
    <li>bla</li>
    <li>bla</li>
    <li>bla</li>
    <li>bla</li>
    <li>bla</li>
</ul>
```

I'm using a media query to style the menu differently when the browser is < 1000px wide:

```
@media screen AND (max-width: 999px) {
    ul#menu li:nth-child(4+) {
          visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work but it illustrates what I want to achieve: hide any list element after the fourth.

I realize there are ways to do this with different classes on the list items, but I want to achieve it with pure CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child(n + 4)` to target them:

```
ul#menu li:nth-child(n + 4) {
    visibility: hidden;  // display: none?
}​
```

You can also use `:nth-child(-n + 3)` to target only the first four elements.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yhsE9/3/**

Comment: You are a hero my dear sir. Will accept the answer in 8 minutes :). Thanks!